# Как вывести корректное значение, математической операций, с значение плавающей точки

Tags: python-3.x

Есть обычная математическая операция, `5.6 * 0,036` но интерпретатор считает слишком точно выводит `0.20159999999999997`  хотя если считать на обычно калькуляторе то выведет `0,2016` Подскажите как можно сделать, что счёт был как в калькуляторе

Код:

```
5,6 * 0.036
```

Comment: Я фигею... два раза повторить одно и то же выражение, и оба раза с ошибкой синтаксиса - причем разной!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from decimal import Decimal
print(Decimal('5.6') * Decimal('0.036'))
```